# How to Broadcast (From one to multiple peers) using Webrtc and Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, npm, webrtc

I know that firebase can be used with webrtc and I was easily able to go through creating a one to one video-audio calling webapp.
I'm Trying to Create a One to several peer broadcasting system,(like twitch) and when i tried to know how it can be done, i found [this](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/webrtc-broadcasting), its pretty old and i cant figure out how i can  implement it with firebase.
If there are any npm packages which can help me achieve this or any guide I can refer to, it would be great if you could share them. I'm using ReactJS.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't created a WebRTC + firebase one-to-many streaming application myself yet, but here are a few resources I'd look at if I was:

- [Coding with Chaim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMbdEnK8h3U)
- [Doug TV site walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhrdFbG6gCU)
- [awesome-webrtc repository](https://github.com/openrtc-io/awesome-webrtc#demos-and-samples) has a lot of gems

Since you asked about other npm packages, there's also [`daily-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@daily-co/daily-js?activeTab=readme), but I'm biased. Full disclosure: I work at Daily. You could use the `daily-js` call object to handle some of the WebRTC complexity. We built a React + `daily-js` webinar, which could be similar to the one-to-many use case you're building (here's the [first blog post](https://www.daily.co/blog/webinartc-build-your-own-webinar-app/) and [sample code](https://github.com/daily-demos/webinar)).